# How can I restrict program access to other users?

Tags: permissions, users

I'm setting up a new user account, and I want to allow access to only certain programs for just that account. How would I go around doing that?

Comment: You might want to explain what type of programs (e.g. are you talking about using a GUI or just commandline shell access?).

Comment: Do you want the new account to be able to (1) execute only a part of the programs everyone else can use (e.g., you want the new user _not_ to run Firefox), or do you want the new account to (2) run everything _plus_ some programs of its own exclusive access? (I.e., in case 2. only the new account would be able to run program "foobar", other people would not.)

Comment: Any programs, and I want to 1) prevent them from running Firefox, for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it with firefox as an example:

1. Create a group `webusers`
2. change the rights of the firefox binary to 750 (root:rwx, webusers:r-x) and the ownership to `root:webusers`
3. add all users who should be allowed to use firefox to the group `webusers`

You can, of course, create groups for all individual programs. Here are the commands for doing it.

```
sudo addgroup webusers
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/firefox
sudo chown root:webusers /usr/bin/firefox
sudo adduser alice webusers
sudo adduser bob webusers
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this is a blacklisting solution, isn't it? This means I'd have to blacklist all applications - which is not very practical. Also: What happens after the next firefox update? Will I have to reset the permissions on `/usr/bin/firefox`?

Comment: An update shouldn't affect the permissions on the file. This is a blacklisting solution in the sense that you need to blacklist apps users shouldn't be able to run and a whitelisting solution in the sense that you need to whitelist the users who should be able to run the blacklisted apps.

Comment: This solution has helped me restrict the forbidden user from accessing the programs successfully, but the permitted users (Alice and Bob in this example) also aren't allowed to access the programs... What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at Pessulus and Gnome Nanny to lock down user accounts.

To lock down specific programs you can use AppArmor. There is no simple configuration to accomplish what you want, but the official Wiki has a nice article on AppArmor:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

Comment: I tried Gnome Nanny, couldn't help. What's Pessulus?

Comment: Pessulus is the official Gnome Lockdown editor.

Comment: Sorry, I want to control individual programs.