# What is the difference between the 'sudo' and 'admin' group?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I noticed that two groups are granted similar-looking permissions in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

My user account with "Administer the system" privileges is in the `admin` group, and there don't appear to be any users in the `sudo` group. What are these two groups for?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and later

Administrators are added to the `sudo` group, but the `admin` group is supported for backward compatibility. From the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Common_Infrastructure):

> Up until Ubuntu 11.10, administrator access using the sudo tool was granted via the `admin` Unix group. In Ubuntu 12.04, administrator access will be granted via the `sudo` group. This makes Ubuntu more consistent with the upstream implementation and Debian. For compatibility purposes, the `admin` group will continue to provide sudo/administrator access in 12.04.

It is not created when you do a fresh install, though it is still present if you upgraded from previous distributions. Either way, the `admin` group appears in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

See [implementation details](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Common_Infrastructure) and the [official documentation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/893842).

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Could you please add an explanation about the difference between `ALL=(ALL)` and `ALL=(ALL:ALL)`?

Comment: Never mind, just saw the answer in Aleksandr's answer below...

Answer (score 26):

## Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier

By default the `sudo` group is not used in *Ubuntu*:

- the user created during installation belongs to `admin` group, not `sudo`;
- no guide or manual I ever read advices to use the `sudo` group;
- no one feels the need to use the `sudo` group, because the `admin` group can do all one needs.

Conversely, on *Debian* the group enabled in `/etc/sudoers` is the `sudo` group, and there is no `admin` group. But the user created during installation is not put in that group, because *Debian* has the `root` account enabled. You should do it explicitly, if you want to.

Also, *Fedora* is similar to *Debian*, having `root` enabled and no default privileges for the user create during installation. But the administrative group configured in `/etc/sudoers` is the more traditional group `wheel`.

In conclusion, I think there is no use for `sudo` group in *Ubuntu*, simply it is a *Debian* heritage.

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, no users are member of `sudo`: `grep '^sudo:' /etc/group` (just installed). Not sure about Debian, I've just added my own name to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: as I said, on Debian you should explicitly add a user to the `sudo` group to gain administrative privileges: `su -c "gpasswd -a $USER sudo"`, no need to modify `/etc/sudoers`. Or you can stand with the Debian way of using directly the `root` account.

Answer (score 25):

No security difference.

Both have 100% unrestricted access to anything provided by the OS.

The difference in your /etc/sudoers is `(ALL)` vs `(ALL:ALL)`. The first one means you can run commands **as any user**. The second - you can run command **as any user** and **as any group**.

The way shown in your /etc/sudoers both groups will need to enter their own password to execute commands as root.

Both can a root shell like this:

```
sudo su
```

Comment: What can't I do without the "as any group" bit?

Comment: If a program is specifically allowed to be executed only by a specific group, then a user with `(ALL)`, that does not belong to that group can't execute that command. Just like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/8842/621061), users that are in the group `admin` and not in the `webuser` group, can't execute `firefox`.