# Run as group fails (sudo -g)

Tags: sudo

I would like to run a command with temporary group membership but it seems that I don't have permission to do that. As an example, if I run `sudo -g internet ls`, I get the message `Sorry, user rudivonstaden is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as rudivonstaden:internet on rudivonstaden-desktop`.

In my limited understanding, this should be governed by the `/etc/sudoers` file, potentially modified by files in `/etc/sudoers.d`. The latter folder only contains the README file, and the sudoers file has the following:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As far as I can tell, that should allow any sudo user to run any file as any group using the -g option. Is there a bug somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: I explicitly added myself to the sudo group, and still got the "Sorry, user" error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working by editing my /etc/sudoers file (with `sudo vimsudo`), and changing the admin group permissions from

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
%admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The sudo group is a bit of a red herring on Ubuntu, it's actually the admin group that defines sudo permissions. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group) for more on how Ubuntu uses the admin and sudo groups.

Comment: The accepted answer to [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group) is not correct anymore. As of Ubuntu 12.04, `sudo` is the main administrative group. If an earlier release is upgraded to 12.04, it will retain the `admin` group, and the `admin` group will still have its power, but that's for backward compatibility.

Comment: On archlinux, you may want to use `wheel` instead. To allow a specific user passwordless access to a specific group, add a line like `thomas ALL=(thomas:vpn) NOPASSWD: ALL`.