# Does oem-config create a user not in sudo group?

Tags: oem

My friend just bought a netbook with Xubuntu preinstalled and the user was created right in store without giving her a root password. Neither was it an *admin* user. Was it oem-config's fault or store stаff's?

Tip:
To solve this boot into recovery mode, choose **root** and execute

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd root
```

Comment: Your "tip" makes me suspect that you don't understand how administrative privileges work in Ubuntu. Enabling the root account as you suggest is [non-standard and recommended against](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account). Why not just [use sudo](http://askubuntu.com/q/7477/1859)?

Comment: Well, yeah, I've forgot to add the line for making the user admin (**Notice**: it's not, that is what the whole question is about), but XFCE asked exactly the root password to add a network connection [since user is not in sudo group]. Also, where do you see *enabling* the root account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Sometimes. Typically it will create one of these, but not both:

- a traditional root user
- a non-root user that has [sudo permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

## Long answer

The [`oem-config`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/oem-config/filelist) command is a symbolic link to [`ubiquity`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/ubiquity/filelist), Ubuntu's standard installer. Ubiquity runs the script `user-setup-ask-oem` to determine how user accounts should be configured, and then the script `user-setup-apply` to actually create them.

The configuration script begins by asking whether a root user should be created:

- If you answer yes, you have the option to also create a non-root user.
- If you answer no, you are forced to create a non-root user.

Later on, the account creation script checks to see if you have decided to create a root user:

- If you have, a root user is created with traditional, implicit administrative privileges. If you have also opted to create a non-root user, that user is created **without** sudo permissions.
- If you've decided not to create a root user, the non-root user is created **with** sudo permissions.

This behavior can be complicated by [preeseed configurations](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/installation-guide/amd64/preseed-contents.html#preseed-account).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu now uses the sudo group rather then the admin group for sudo access.

Post the output of:

```
id <user>
```

Where user is the user created with the oem-config ;)

See also [What is the difference between the 'sudo' and 'admin' group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group)

Comment: I'm not asking about how to identify if user is admin, I'm asking if users created by oem-config end up being admins. Are they? I don't know if it was created by oem-config or some scripts written by the shop.