# Sudoers.d Permissions denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root, chmod

I am running ubuntu 14.04 in DardDrive. I was taking the Steps for Setting up and Running `sudo` located here http://snag.gy/JAGgt.jpg. But every I type `sudo "whatever"`  as user ($), I get the following message:

```
 sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied
 sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/ken: Permission denied.
```

so I leveled up as root and did `ls -l | grep sud`. See the following:

```
root@ken-:/etc# ls -l | grep sud
-rw-r-----  1 root root       745 mar 19 12:11 sudoers
drwxr-----  2 root root      4096 mar 19 14:53 sudoers.d
```

Based on the instructions on how to configure `sudo`, I should make a directory named same as my username in `sudoers.d` directory and in that file I have to just type `ALL(ALL)LL` on the user name. but, I also did a `chmod 440` on that file, which makes it look like this:

```
root@ken-Inspiron-5558:/etc/sudoers.d# ls -l
total 8
-r--r----- 1 root root  22 mar 19 14:53 ken
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 mar 19 12:16 README
```

At this point when I level down using `sudo su ken`, and want to get into sudoers.d I keep getting the permission denied  statement.

I am not even able to access sudoers.d as user, see this:

```
ken@ken-Inspiron-5558:/etc$ cd /etc/sudoers.d/
 bash: cd: /etc/sudoers.d/: Permission denied-
```

Comment: Why are you trying to manually set up `sudo`?  `sudo` is automatically set up on Ubuntu systems in almost all circumstances.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here. I don't see any reason you should be able to access `/etc/sudoers.d` as a normal user.

Comment: Normal users may not read or modify the `/etc/sudoers*` files and directories, this is correct and intended for security reasons.

Comment: And I have no idea for what Linux distribution the guide you describe is intended, but it has definitely nothing to do with Ubuntu! Ubuntu comes with everything already configured and ready to use.

Comment: See my answer guys, his directory navigation issues have nothing to do with sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, based on the instructions it's `ALL=(ALL) ALL` , so there's one mess up.

Second , instructions say  **If your system does not already have sudo set up and enabled** , which you *really* should have checked before doing the rest.

Third, just remove that `ken` file. Your username is added to `sudo` group automatically during installation (if that's the username you picked during installation of course, and not created manually).

Finally, look at your `/etc/sudoers.d` permissions:

```
root@ken-:/etc# ls -l | grep sud
-rw-r-----  1 root root       745 mar 19 12:11 sudoers
drwxr-----  2 root root      4096 mar 19 14:53 sudoers.d
```

**A directory requires execute permissions bit set in order to navigate into it**. You cannot navigate into the directory **because only the owner( root ) has x set for it** ([Related post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/283405/permission-denied-to-cd-into-a-directory-even-though-permissions-are-correct) demonstrates that well enough). So your navigation to `/etc/sudoers.d`  issue has *nothing* to do with `sudo` but with folder permission bits

But if you are still unconvinced  heres a demo on a directory, owned by my user, in my home folder.

```
$ ls -ld testdir                                               
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 Mar 17 16:34 testdir/
$ chmod -x testdir
$ cd testdir
/bin/mksh: cd: /home/xieerqi/testdir: Permission denied
```

Comment: Correct catch that `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` is commented out, but Ubuntu never adds single user names to `/etc/sudoers` automatically. The privileges are granted through membership of the `sudo` group only by default.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks, good catch. What I mean is that  when you install Ubuntu and create the username , you will be added to `sudo` group automatically.

Comment: The pound sign in `#includedir` does _not_ make it a comment.  See `man sudoers`.

Comment: @DerekVeit Didn't know that. Thanks. I'll edit my answer in a moment

Answer (score 2):

You should have not added anything to `/etc/sudoers.d/`!
This is simply unnecessary and dangerous (as you see). All admin users (including the default user account that gets created during the installation) are already allowed to use `sudo` to run commands with root privileges.

Remove the file `/etc/sudoers.d/ken` again and revert all changes you might have done to `/etc/sudoers.d`.
You can use `pkexec` as temporary replacement for `sudo` to fix the issues while that does not work:

```
pkexec rm /etc/sudoers.d/ken
```

---

Admin users on Ubuntu are defined by their group membership in the `sudo` (formerly `admin`) group.

When you add new admin users through the Unity Control Center GUI, it will take care of those group memberships automatically.

When you add a new user from the terminal using `sudo adduser USERNAME`, it will not be a member of any additional group. In this case, you have to add those two groups manually to make the account an administrator that is allowed to use `sudo`:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME sudo
```

---

And in the rare case where you really would have to edit `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, **never** do that manually but **always use `sudo visudo` to edit it! This command will verify the files and check for errors before applying the changes and prevent leaving you with a ruined `sudo` command.

Comment: so in order to remove /sudoers.d/ken, I should level up to root, by I get the following: 


  -  ken@ken-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo su


  -  sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied


  -  sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/kenneth: Permission denied

Comment: Yes, you messed up your `sudo` command by adding a wrong configuration file. Use `pkexec rm /etc/sudoers.d/ken`.

Comment: I did, thanks, but, now, it is weird, because,  when I level down to my ken user, and I do  $sudo ls, I actually get my list of files, for example, in my home directory,  I get the following: ken@ken-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo ls
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied
Photos           Videos         Music        Files      Personal.

This is like if I was getting denied permissions on a README file but the permissions on the README file are the following: _____________# ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/README 
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 mar 19 12:16 /etc/sudoers.d/README

Comment: Did you modify the content of the readme file? When you open it (as root), is there any line in it that does not start with a `#` sign? Did you make any modifications to `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Can you take a look at this: http://snag.gy/lnJqV.jpg. it is the README file which I had to open as root of course using vim. here are the permissions of this file http://snag.gy/Zvwm8.jpg Should I change it ?

Comment: @heemayl I disagree with your edit. When I check the group memberships of the default admin user (UID 1000) on all of my machines, none of them is member of an `admin` group. My current group memberships on this machine are `bytecommander adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare kvm libvirtd`. There doesn't even exist any `admin` group. Therefore I rolled back your edit. If you want to discuss it, please reply to this comment or in chat.

Comment: You don't get it..check `sudo grep admin /etc/sudoers` ..`admin` group is legacy, it was before `sudo` group was introduced..it is just kept for legacy's sake..by default no user is a member of the group (check `getent group admin`), although you can assign one....also `adm` is just for logs permission..no offense but you should do your homework first honestly before reverting back my edit..

Comment: @heemayl Okay, the `adm` group is probably my mistake. But I still have no `admin` groups on any machine. `sudo adduser bytecommander admin` reports back that the `admin` group does not exist. Also it's not in `/etc/group`. That's at least the case on 15.10.

Comment: I'm on 14.04, and `admin` isn't created ( by default ), but it's part of `/etc/sudoers` file, because `admin` group as far as I understand from [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/122500/295286) exists for backward compatability with older systems ( before 12.04 LTS ) where `admin` group was the superuser type of group.  `adm` group [apparently exists only for being able to read logs](http://superuser.com/a/86349/418028).   In a nut shell, `adm` isn't related to `sudo`, `admin` is in `/etc/sudoers` for compatability. Hope that helps ?

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the nice explanation and linked reference. Now I understand what heemayl wanted. But as the `admin` groups seems abandoned since 12.04 inclusive, it's probably better not to use it.

Comment: @ByteCommander Well , it could serve as a workaround, but i really see no reason why OP cannot `su` to root and purge `sudo` with apt-get , then reinstall it (if that can help the situation of course)

Comment: @Serg Dunno if that works... And I'm not going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue by elevating as root, then did root@root# chmod 755 /root/etc/sudoers and sudoers.d. Since I am the only one who uses the computer, I don't really mind having permissions set open for ugo.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu has sudo already installed. Normal users will not be able to change directory to /etc/sudoers.d

In screenshot you have provided, author want to use `sudo` command as `student` user.

For this you have to first create a user called student

```
# useradd student


Add student to sudoers
# vi /etc/sudoers.d/student

insert following in it
student ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

save the file

restart ssh
```

Now hopefully you can run all sudo commands and be a sudo like below ;)

```
$ sudo su
```

Comment: I don't like your answer, because there's no need to add a user to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow him to become root using `sudo`. That's what the `sudo` group (formerly `admin` group, as I just learned) is for in Ubuntu. Also, one should *never* edit `/etc/sudoers` directly but always only using the command `visudo` as root (or with `sudo`), because that only saves the changes if the new file would parse correctly and does not contain syntax errors that would break the entire `sudo` system. Also, why use `NOPASSWD`!? That's a huge security risk!

Comment: correct in the sense that sudoers file should be edit as visudo and not vi only. That is why I have not edited sudoers file itself (check out above again).  If you are concern about security risk then you shouldn't use NOPASSWD and limit sudo commands.

Comment: Syntax errors in files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` also break the entire sudo sytsem, as you can see in the question. All the files there are simply appended to `/etc/sudoers` and then the whole thing is evaluated at once.