# What is the difference between the group root and the group sudo? Why root user by default is not a member of the group sudo?

Tags: sudo, root, user-management, groups, visudo

I am quite confused regarding this matter.

As far as I know the user root has all the privelages.

Also all the users of the group sudo has all privelages.

But the user root by default is not a member of the group sudo. Then how can the user root be sudo user?

Please explain the entire concept to me.

To be noted the commands mentioned below produces the output mentioned below:

```
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho# compgen -u
-----
-----
root
rancho
-----
-----
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho# compgen -g
-----
-----
root
rancho
sudo
-----
-----
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho# getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:rancho
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho# getent group root
root:x:0
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho# visudo
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        rootpw
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

:x
$root@lenovo:/home/rancho#
```

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/299324/443564)

Comment: And you can find plenty more information by Googling "sudo vs root" or something similar.

Comment: @wjandrea clearly the two questions are not same. Here I have seperate user whose name is root. It is not about root password. But the user root does not belong to the sudoers group. On the hand only those users who are in the sudoers group can gain root access. And there is no information regarding this by plenty of google searching. Please completely read my question and then comment.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand what you were asking. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that **root** has all privileges, but saying that **sudoers** have all privileges is not quite correct. They are *allowed to attain* all privileges by using `sudo` to run a command as **root**. That includes running a root prompt, using a command like `sudo -i`.

**root** is not a **sudoer** because it is already **root** - it doesn't need to become **root** to run commands.

Comment: Then if I give the command usermod -a -G sudo root

and include root in the group sudo, what difference does it make?

Comment: I don't think adding root to the sudo group would change anything. Root can already run `sudo` because it's root.

Comment: After I setup wordpress I get access denied error but after if I include root in sudoers group and myself in root group in addition to sudoers group, the error goes away. Why is that?

Comment: Note: I am also not present in root group by deafult. I am present in only sudo group.

Comment: I'm not sure about that Wordpress error, but you shouldn't add yourself to the root group. You are not present in the root group by default for security reasons: the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)