# How do I limit users in a certain group to using a few specific applications?

Tags: permissions, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I restrict program access to other users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users)

I want to let users in a particular group use Firefox, Remmina Remote Desktop and Printers, but no other applications or utilities. How can I do that?

Comment: similar question [http://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users