# Is it possibe to add a password to the Guest Account in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, login, password

I'm trying to create a fairly basic Kiosk type installation for a Visitor Centre, but they need to have a password on the machine to make sure they know when somebody wants to use it (so they can charge them).
It seems a password can't be set on the Guest account, (which is the ideal type of account for their requirements), is that the case?  If so, is there an alternative anyone might recommend?  I need to make sure that any user cannot mess up the installation, and also cannot mess up the user account.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/227261/how-do-i-set-a-password-for-guest-login

Comment: So basically the answer is "No you can't, you'll have to create another user acount".  Okay, no problem, but are there any instructions anyone can suggest for locking down the account so users can't change, remove or add  anything please?  I can't seem to find much...  maybe my wording in search engines isn't quite right.

Comment: Go to settings and user accounts, unlock it and make a `standard` account, give it a password. Now this account can't edit the system without, the password of your administer account, so can't install anything or edit any thing on /. To make the new accounts home folder read only, log in as your admin and run `sudo chmod 744 /home/your/standard/account/user`, now only root can create or remove files in this folder, hope that helps

Comment: To remove the ubuntu `guest` account http://www.techlw.com/2012/05/disable-guest-account-in-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: It's a start - thanks.  Need to find a way to stop anyone playing around with desktop settings, panel settings etc. now.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please see here for that http://askubuntu.com/questions/307663/prevent-users-from-accessing-system-settings