# How do I lock my clock?

Tags: time, 17.04

Env: Ubuntu 17.04

I want to prevent unauthorized changes to my system clock.

e.g. requiring a password to change it, or just remove privileges from users to change it.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307663/prevent-users-from-accessing-system-settings