# How to create user without any application access

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, users, ubuntu-gnome, user-management

I want to create a user with less privileges like that new user should only have the certain application access,  all other application menus should be disabled or hide from the main menu.

For example I am creating an user called user1 and user2 . The both user should only can see the firefox after logged in.

Your help would be much appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: kiosk mode is the option.. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#0 or search Ububtu help with kiosk as key search

Comment: You need to add a group firefox and change the permissions on the firefox application so only users in the firefox group can access it and use this method for all applications you need to restrict to specific users as per this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users