# App locker in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I wanna lock a software application (for example, CS: GO); so I want an app locker.

Can you please help me find an app locker?

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly in particular state your version of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

- You can hide certain applications from non-techy users by hidding the menu entries in the Application overview for these accounts. You can do so by setting `Hidden=true` in the application's desktop file in the `.local/share/applications` folder of the user. Removing user right access will prevent a somewhat techy user that has no root access to revert this.
- You can hide terminal commands from such users by changing their search $PATH. You can setup a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) to make it more difficult for somewhat techy users to change this.
- You can [change groups and execute permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8149/how-can-i-restrict-program-access-to-other-users) of selected executables to allow execution only by specific users.

Sufficiently skilled users having physical access to the hardware can always circumvent, but the tools above are sufficient to "keep honest people out".

For the first point, if you want to restrict strongly, you can hide any application launcher in `/usr/share/applications`: copy all to `/urs/local/share/applications` and hide the copies. Then you can enable selected applications with a copy of the `.desktop` file in the user's home folder.